The creation date of files changes when they are moved on the SD card mounted in the smartphone
I’m trying to organize photos and files stored on an SD card using file explorer apps on my smartphone. However, I’m facing an issue where simply moving files to another location within the SD card using these file explorer apps causes the creation date of the files to change. For instance, after moving files to a different location on the SD card using a file explorer app, then disconnecting the SD card from the smartphone and connecting it to a computer, I can see that the creation dates of the files have changed.

I have tried using various file explorer apps (such as X-plore and Total Commander) to resolve this issue, but the problem still persists. Currently, I am using a Galaxy Note 20 Ultra 5G with One UI version 5.1 and Android version 13.0.

The filesystem used by Android for the SD card (exFAT) only supports storing times for:

Access
Modify: when the file or metadata was modified
Change: when the file was changed (this can be set arbitrarily)

Therefore you can't keep the original creation time.
See also this related question: Change file creation timestamp on an exFAT volume from Linux

Thank you for your response. As of now, it seems there is no way to preserve the creation dates of the data stored on an SD card when transferring them.

Thanks for the update! Does the Modify timestamp automatically get set when the Change timestamp gets set (and vice versa)?

If you modify the file itself, both get updated. If you modify the change timestamp, it will update the modify timestamp too. As far as I know, you cannot set the modify timestamp directly.
